# Variable inside eval or as assignment of eval

Tags: php

there's a difference assigning a variable inside an eval or outside it as assignment?

```
eval ("\$variable = \"\$code\";")
$variable = eval($code)
```

I searched a lot for that information but I didn't find something about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference.

In the first case - `eval("\$variable = \"\$code\";");` - the variable `$variable` will be declared, BUT its value will be a **string** of the code stored in vraiable `$code`.

Whereas the second case - `$variable = eval($code);` - will also declare a variable `$variable`, BUT the value will be anything the `eval` function returns ([see docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)) and it WILL **process the code** stored in variable `$code`.